# IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited not working in ORMLite

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I am using :

```
using (dbConn = openDBConnection(_dbConnectionFactory))
using (var trans =   dbConn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
    {         
        searchResults = dbConn.Select<T>(SearchExpression);
    }
```

But still my SQL profiler is getting a query without nolock.